# Matrix of a given operator $A \otimes A$

Tags: matrices, tensor-products, tensors

Let $V$ be a 3-dimensional vector space with an ordered basis $e_{1}$, $e_{2}$, $e_{3}$, and $A: V → V$ be a linear operator given by its matrix relative to the ordered basis $e_{1}$, $e_{2}$, $e_{3}$ as follows:

$A = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 1 & 4 \\
-1 & 3 & 2 \\
1 & -2 & 4 \end{array} \right)$.

$V \otimes V$ has basis $e_{i} \otimes e_{j} \forall 1 \leq i, j \leq 3$.

I have to find $A \otimes A: V \otimes V → V \otimes V$ in matrix form relative to the basis $(e_{i} \otimes e_{j})_{i, j}$.

I basically do not know how to do this at all. Can you lay out a rather detailed explanation of how to do so and what this means as you go along, preferably with the concrete example being worked through?

Would it simply be a $6 \times 6$ matrix with integer coefficients such that it is block diagonal, with the diagonal blocks being the $3 \times 3$ matrix presented earlier and the off-diagonal blocks being the $3 \times 3$ matrix of only $0$'s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A\otimes A$ is a 9 by 9 matrix, which can be written as:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
2A & A & 4A \\
-A & 3A & 2A \\
A & -2A & 4A \end{pmatrix},$$
that is, $e_i \otimes e_j \mapsto \left(\sum_{k} a_{ki} e_k\right) \otimes\left(\sum_{l} a_{lj} e_l\right)$.

Comment: Can you explain to me why?

Comment: By definition, $(A\otimes B)(x\otimes y) = Ax \otimes By$.

Comment: Also the dimension of $V \otimes V$ is $3\times 3 = 9$, having the basis $e_{ij} = e_i\otimes e_j$.  So think about what the $(ij,kl)$ entry of $A\otimes A$ must be - it must be $a_{ik} a_{jl}$.

Comment: And make the mapping $e_{11} \mapsto e_1$, $e_{12} \mapsto e_2$, $e_{13} \mapsto e_3$, $e_{21} \mapsto e_4$, $e_{22} \mapsto e_5$, ... $e_{33} \mapsto e_9$.

Comment: Can you more explicitly show me how to go from $e_{i} \otimes e_{j} \mapsto \left(\sum_{k} a_{k,i} e_{k}\right) \otimes\left(\sum_{l} a_{l,j} e_{l}\right)$ to the matrix?

Comment: Because $A e_i = \sum_k a_{ki} e_k$.